# model doesn't exist in current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to build my own mailer controller to handle custom email generation.

I have a default layout mailer that handles all the common parts of the mail template.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<header style="width: 100%; height: auto; padding: 20px 20px 10px 20px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0; background-color: #eee; color: #555 !important; ">
    <h1 style="margin-top: -10px; margin-bottom: 0;height:80px; ">
        <img style="float:left;" src="https://mylogoimage" alt="logo" />
        <span style="padding: 30px 0 0 10px; float: left; color: #555 !important; font-size: 28px;">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Confirm Registration</span>
        <a style="padding: 35px 40px 0 0; float: right; color: #555 !important; font-size: 14px;" href="#">View in Browser</a>
    </h1>
</header>
<div id="emailbodytext">
   @RenderBody()
</div>
<footer style="background-color: #eee; color: #555 !important; height:50px;padding-top:10px;">
    <p style="margin-left:25px;">
        <strong><span style="font-size:1em;font-style:italic;">You are receiving this email because you registered an account at TraderToolkit.com</span></strong>
        <img style="float:right;margin-right:25px;padding-bottom:10px;" src="https://mylogoimage" alt="logo" /><br />
    </p>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I created a Registration view that uses the layout shown above. Which VS generates as;

```
@{
Layout = "~/Views/Mailers/_LayoutMailer.cshtml";
}
```

I then add my model to reference

```
@model EmailViewModels.RegistrationConfirmOutputViewModel
```

VS2015 is fine with all that. Then I add the html for the view.

```
<section style="font-size:1.1em;">
<h3 style="margin-left: 10px;">Greetings @model.FullName,</h3>
<p style="margin-left: 25px;">
    You (or someone else) entered this email address to register an account at @model.ApplicationName.<br /><br/>
    The request was sent from this IPAddress -- <span style="font-size:1.15em;font-weight:bold;">@model.IpAddress</span>.
    <br />
    The approximate geographic location from where this request was sent is <span style="font-size:1.15em;font-weight:bold;">@model.IpLocation</span>.
    <br /><br />
    If you sent the request and wish to confirm your registration please click the button below to complete your registration
    <br />
    @Html.ActionLink("Confirm Registration", "ConfirmRegistration", "Account", new { parameters = @model.UserId }, null)

    <br /><br />
    If you feel your email account has been compromised please take the appropriate steps to secure your account.<br />
    Please click the button below so we can remove this registration request.<br />
    @Html.ActionLink("Delete Request", "ChangePassword","Account",new { parameters = @model.UserId },null)

    <br /><br />
    Thank you.<br />
    The staff at @model.ApplicationName
</p>
```

And this is where it falls apart. Layout, in the declaration is now red as are every reference to `@model`. Error now says :

> Cannot resolve symbol Layout

None of the `@model` properties exist in current context.

Is there something about views that use a layout that cannot use a model reference? I am new to learning MVC and not sure how to proceed.

Also, am I using the `Html.ActionLink` properly because `@Html` is in red as well.

**Update**
I tried recreating the view by referencing the viewmodel in the view create dialog (referencing the application ocntext too) by that wouldnt create the view saying there was no key defined in the entity (RegistrationConfirmationOutputViewModel). Why would a viewmodel need a key? Does that view create dialog only reference Domain models?

Comment: Are you using Resharper? Sometimes Reshaper messes itself with project references. Try to clean your solution and see what goes on.

Comment: Sometimes this is fixed by closing and reopening VS.

Comment: shouldn't be model variable name with first uppercase `@Model.FullName`?

Comment: I tried all the above. Not fixed so I deleted the RegistrationConfirmation view and started over by adding a new view, empty, model class set to the model in the applicationcontext and got an error generating saying the entity has no key defined. Since its just a view model why would it need a key?